# Why java regex replaceAll() returns only last match

Tags: java, regex

I have a string that contains html code and trying to replace the domain names of different URLs in it to `http://localhost` but the regex I am applying always return the last match instead of the whole string.
Please see the code snippet below

```
String data = "https://example.com/abc/xyz https://sub.example.com/abc/def https://sub-example.com/abc/ijk";
System.out.println(data);
data = data.replaceFirst("(http|https)://.*/abc/", "http://localhost/");
System.out.println(data);
```

Below is the output this code is generating

```
http://localhost/ijk
```

What am I doing wrong here... Please let me know

Comment: `.*` is greedy that is matching longest string before last `/abc/` Use `.*?`

Comment: You have a greedy match that simply spawns from the first https up to the very end of your input.

Comment: Use `.*?` to make the * less greedy for characters

Comment: This resolves the issue.. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rerstrict the `.*` pattern as it matches any 0+ chars as many as possible. Use `\S*`, any 0+ chars other than whitespace.

Also, you need to use `.replaceAll` to replace all occurrences.

So, use

```
data = data.replaceAll("https?://\\S*/abc/", "http://localhost/");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TgrOi0/1).

**Details**

- `https?` - `http` or `https`
- `://` - a literal `://` substring
- `\\S*` - any 0+ chars other than whitespace
- `/abc/` - an `/abc/` substring.

Comment: Sorry it was a type.. Using replacell() in the actual program

Comment: @faheem205 I see. The point is that `.*`is matching too much here. Note that the pattern might need adjustment if the URLs may contain whitespace. However, it cannot be `.*?` as the `/abc/` might make the match again too long. You might consider something like [`"https?://(?:(?!https?://).)*?/abc/"`](https://regex101.com/r/TgrOi0/2).